# Checking next character in a string

Tags: python, string, list

I want to check the next character in a string. My code at the moment is this:

I input a word (e.g. `hedge`).

```
split_word = word.split()
empty_list = []
for i in split_word:
    if i in "aeiou":
        if split_word[i+1] in "drlsj":
            empty_list.append(i)
            empty_list.append(i+1)
```

Now obviously the notation of `i+1` is garbage, but that was just to help clarify the idea that i want to somehow access the character after `i` (once its passed the if check).

Comment: Can you show your expected out put and explain what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Martijn's anwer is the best. You can also have a look at [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can loop over *pairs* of characters; that would let you check both:

```
for a, b in zip(split_word, split_word[1:]):
    if a in "aeiou" and b in "drlsj":
        empty_list += [a, b]
```

The [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) pairs up values from the inputs; first elements together, second elements together, etc. Since the input gives the word and the word *minus the first character*, you get pairs of characters along the word. For `hedge`, that'd be `('h', 'e')` then `('e', 'd')` then `('d', 'g')`, etc. Only complete pairs are produced, there is no `(None, 'e')` pair at the end.

Your own attempt did not include an index, only the characters from the word. You could have used the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to add an index to the loop. However, you need to be careful you don't end up trying to index beyond the length of the word! Loop over all of the word *minus the last character* in that case:

```
for i, a in enumerate(split_word[:-1]):
    b = split_word[i + 1]
    # etc.
```